# Simplify multiple if else statements

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to simplify multiple if else statements.

I'm trying to loop through the slick slider to grab each slide and link it with a li item to display the heading for that particular slide

Please see code below for what i have at the moment

```
$('#tab-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    if(currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-1').index()) {
        $('.tabs li.tab-1').css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }else {
        $('.tabs li.tab-1').css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }

    if(currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-2').index()) {
        $('.tabs li.tab-2').css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }else {
        $('.tabs li.tab-2').css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }

    if(currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-3').index()) {
        $('.tabs li.tab-3').css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }else {
        $('.tabs li.tab-3').css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }

    if(currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-4').index()) {
        $('.tabs li.tab-4').css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }else {
        $('.tabs li.tab-4').css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }

    if(currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-5').index()) {
        $('.tabs li.tab-5').css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }else {
        $('.tabs li.tab-5').css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: can you add your fiddle here

Comment: If you have a working code and is looking for a review, you might want to check https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with what you want is to add an `active` class which will have your desired css properties. I'm not sure if your `.tab-X` is the same as `currentSlide` variable on slide but you can do something like this :

```
$('#tab-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
   $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
   $('.tabs li.tab-'+currentSlide).addClass('active');
});
```

And your `CSS` :

```
.active {
   font-weight: bold;
   /* Your other desired properties */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could populate an array with all 5 descriptor names, and then iterate it:

```
var desc = ['.tabs li.tab-1', '.tabs li.tab-2', '.tabs li.tab-3', '.tabs li.tab-4',
           '.tabs li.tab-5'];

for (var i=0, len=desc.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (currentSlide === $(desc[i]).index()) {
        $(desc[i]).css({
            'font-weight' : 'bold',
        });
    }
    else {
        $(desc[i]).css({
            'font-weight' : 'normal',
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't actually change the amount of code which needs to execute (it increases it slightly), but it does solve the problem of removing those repetitive if checks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use switch statement?

```
$('#tab-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){    
       switch (currentSlide) {
            case $('.tabs li.tab-1').index():
                $('.tabs li.tab-1').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                });
                break;
            case $('.tabs li.tab-2').index():
                $('.tabs li.tab-2').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                });
            case $('.tabs li.tab-3').index():
                $('.tabs li.tab-3').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                });
            case $('.tabs li.tab-4').index():
                $('.tabs li.tab-4').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                });
            case $('.tabs li.tab-5').index():
                $('.tabs li.tab-5').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'bold',
                });
                break;
            default:
                $('.tabs li.tab-1,.tabs li.tab-2,.tabs li.tab-3,.tabs li.tab-4,.tabs li.tab-5').css({
                    'font-weight' : 'normal',
                });
        }
});
```

Or use || in if loop like this:

```
$('#tab-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        if (currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-1').index() || currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-2').index() || currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-3').index() ||
            currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-4').index() || currentSlide === $('.tabs li.tab-5').index()) {
            $('.tabs li.tab-1,.tabs li.tab-2,.tabs li.tab-3,.tabs li.tab-4,.tabs li.tab-5').css({
                'font-weight': 'bold',
            });
        } else {
            $('.tabs li.tab-1,.tabs li.tab-2,.tabs li.tab-3,.tabs li.tab-4,.tabs li.tab-5').css({
                'font-weight': 'normal',
            });
        }
    });
```